# Обработка исключений c# try-catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

есть код, необходимо чтобы он передавал все вызванные исключения в текстбокс, но этого не происходит, подскажите пожалуйста что делаю не так?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cvet;
            try
            {
                cvet = Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text);
                if (cvet == "Red")
                    textBox5.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                        if (cvet == "Blue")
                            textBox5.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                                if (cvet == "Green")
                                    textBox5.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
            }
            catch 
            {
                textBox5.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.5f);
                textBox5.Text += ("Цвет окна: Такого цвета нет");

            }
         }
```

Comment: Потому что это локальная обработка исключений после нажатия на button, т.е исключение должно быть вызвано внутри button1_Click для того, чтобы блок catch смог захватить исключение вызванное в блоке try

Comment: @Kalmankantaja можете показать пример, пожалуйста, не особо понимаю как это должно выглядеть

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148156/winforms-global-exception-handling

Comment: @Kalmankantaja так у меня тоже находиться внутри button1_Click

Comment: Странный код... 1. Зачем тут конвертация в строку, когда `textBox3.Text` это и так строка? 2. Зачем такая "елочка", у вас нету вложенности `if`'ов, они все отдельно друг от друга, а вы их размещаете так, будто они вложены. Если `if` без скобок, то после него только одна строка будет подходить под условие, а не все после. 3. Зачем вам тут вообще перечисление, если можно написать одной строкой `textBox5.BackColor = Color.FromName(cvet);`? 4. Зачем тут вообще `try/catch`, какую ошибку он тут ловит? 5. Очень странно решение в установки шрифта в `catch`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, try/catch нужен по заданию в универе, к сожалению не могу однозначно сказать по поводу их использования, задача выглядит так: Класс «окно», включающий координаты и цвет окна, текст в окне, 
цвет текста и функцию изменения текста в окне;

Comment: @EvgeniyZ и использовать надо конкретно try/catch , если бы можно было не использовать я бы воспользовался else и не морочил никому голову с вопросами :)

Comment: @МихаилДужарь Вот смотрите, в вашем коде сейчас есть `try/catch`, задайте теперь вопрос, он когда-либо выполнится, попадет в `catch`? Нет, а почему? Давайте смотреть... `Convert.ToString(textBox3.Text)` - конвертация строки в строку, выдаст исключение? Нет. Может `if (cvet == "Red")`? Нет. А может `textBox5.BackColor = Color.Maroon;`? Да тоже нет, ибо контролы у вас уже созданы, а больше тут и нечему выдавать ошибки. Собственно, что у вас в блоке `try` должно упасть, чтобы выполнился код в `catch`? Пока он бесполезен тут вовсе, может стоит задать вопрос преподавателю?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ на счет преподавателя не вариант, ей нужен try catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы перехватить исключение, нужно чтобы оно возникало.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string cvet = textBox3.Text;
        switch (cvet)
        {
            case "Red":
                textBox5.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                break;
            case "Blue":
                textBox5.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            case "Green":
                textBox5.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Такого цвета нет");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textBox5.AppendText($"Цвет окна: {ex.Message}{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
}
```